# how to properly remove days if its 0? (DateTime)

Tags: php

```
function secondsToTime( $seconds )
{
    $dtF = new DateTime( "@0" );
    $dtT = new DateTime( "@$seconds" );
    $r = $dtF->diff( $dtT )->format( "%ad, %hh, %im and %ss" );
    print( $r );
    if( strpos( $r, "0h, ", 0 ) !== false )
        $r = str_replace( "0h, ", "", $r );
    if( strpos( $r, "0d, ", 0 ) !== false )
        $r = str_replace( "0d, ", "", $r );

    return $r;
}
```

I tried with this code, but in hindsight I realized that this would make 50d 5h say 55h. how do I best remove 0 days, hours?

Answer (score 0):

Having a string that has a unified structure is easier to use, that's why I replace "and" with ",".
This can be fixed if it's important.

I explode and look at the first character of each part of the array, if it's a zero, remove it.
Once I find a none zero stop looping.
Then implode back to string format.

```
function secondsToTime( $seconds )
{
    $dtF = new DateTime( "@0" );
    $dtT = new DateTime( "@$seconds" );
    $r = $dtF->diff( $dtT )->format( "%ad, %hh, %im, %ss" );
    //print( $r );
    $arr = explode(", ", $r);
    Foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        If(substr($val, 0,1) == "0"){
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }Else{
            Break;
        }
    }
    return implode(", ",$arr);
}

Echo secondsToTime( 50+3600*5 );
```

https://3v4l.org/PIrpS

You can use this return to get the "and" there.

```
return implode(", ",array_slice($arr,0,count($arr)-1)) . ($seconds > 59 ? " and " : "") . End($arr);
```

This will add "and" if it's more than 59 seconds, else only type out the seconds.